# Local write-only Cassandra node

Tags: cassandra

I have a process which generates measurements pretty rapidly, and I'm looking to store them in Cassandra. The process runs on a server in a data centre, and there is a Cassandra node in the same data centre, as well as another. If the server generating the measurements loses connectivity, I'd like the measurements to be logged locally, and then when connectivity is restored for the data to get processed properly by the ring. Is it possible to run some kind of local write-only Cassandra node (which uses minimal hard disc space), which is connected to the other nodes, or do I have to go via some kind of message bus?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is "write-only" nodes and a central node. Cassandra does not have a direct support for that. 
Here are your options

Have a messaging bus like Apache Kafka (my personal favorite) on each of the write-nodes and on the main server. Write the data into kafka on each node and then use kafka-mirror-maker to mirror each node's kafka to the main server. On the main server, write a small app that will write all the data that it receives from kafka to cassandra. If the connection goes off, node's kafka will be still saving data, when the connection comes back mirror-maker will continue at the point where it stopped.

or

For each node that you have, create a separate set of all your keyspaces, assign one datacenter to each node and one to your central server, set the replication settings that each node will be replicating its keyspaces to the central server (i.e. to the central datacenter) but not to other nodes. For example you have 2 logical keyspaces (kA, kB), 2 nodes (dc1, dc2 datacenter names respectively on each node) and main server (datacenter name: dc0).
You need to create the kA_dc1 kB_dc1 , kA_dc2 kB_dc2 keyspaces and set the following replication settings.

- kA_dc1, kB_dc1: replication to **dc1 and dc0**
- kA_dc2, kB_dc2: replication to **dc2 and dc0**

After that you need to modify your program to query all keyspaces (as keyspaces contain the same schemas, that should be easy)